# Copy value from a row to another row in the same table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

Here my table "Stocks"

[image]

This is product quantities from 3 différents shops. As you can see, all the products have a quantity value provided for "shop 1" but not for "shop 3" (quantity for "shop 2" doesn't matter). I need a sql query to copy all products quantities from "Shop 1" to "Shop 3".

Regarding the previous screenshoot, insert the following rows:

id_product - id_shop - quantity

2136 - 3 - 9

2138 - 3 - 2

Also, if product quantity already exist in "shop 3", update the quantity to the value of the quantity from "shop 1".

Maybe i need to try 2 queries? One for the update if exists the one for insert if not exists ?

Don't know if is important but column id_stock (not on the screenshot) is auto-increment.

Tried this query for the update part and seems to work but i don't know for the insert part. My table have 6000+ rows:

```
UPDATE stocks sa
JOIN stocks sb ON sa.id_product = sb.id_product AND sb.quantity IS NOT NULL
SET sa.quantity = sb.quantity
WHERE sa.id_shop = 3
```

Result of "show create table stocks" query:

```
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `id_stock_available` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_product_attribute` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_shop` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_shop_group` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `physical_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reserved_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `depends_on_stock` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `out_of_stock` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_stock_available`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_sqlstock` (`id_product`,`id_product_attribute`,`id_shop`,`id_shop_group`),
  KEY `id_shop` (`id_shop`),
  KEY `id_shop_group` (`id_shop_group`),
  KEY `id_product` (`id_product`),
  KEY `id_product_attribute` (`id_product_attribute`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17869 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Please add the result of show create table stocks as text.

Comment: I updated my post with the result.

Comment: You could use `REPLACE INTO ... SELECT ...` or `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`